# Misdirected Request HTTP 421 Error when using Nginx but not Apache as reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

For a specific use-case, I want to put a reverse proxy (RP) in the cloud in front of an application already packaged with another RP listening to HTTPS only. I don't have any access to the configuration of the application backend and its reverse proxy.

**cloudreverseproxy --https--> upstreamreverseproxy --https--> upstreambackend**

For the following example, cloudreverseproxy url is "mycloudreverseproxy.com" and upstreamreverseproxy is "myupstream.com"

When using Nginx as reverse proxy with standard ssl config I get a Misdirected Request HTTP 421 error when browsing https://mycloudreverseproxy.com but when using Apache with a similar config, everything works perfectly. I also used openresty as upstream to troubleshoot the headers sent by the cloudreverseproxy but everything seems very similar between Nginx and Apache.

Here is Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name             mycloudreverseproxy.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloudreverseproxy.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloudreverseproxy.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloudreverseproxy.com/chain.pem;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass                         https://myupstream.com/;
        proxy_http_version                 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }

}
```

And the Apache one :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mycloudreverseproxy.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloudreverseproxy.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycloudreverseproxy.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / https://myupstream.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://myupstream.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Any why Apache works and not Nginx ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue, where Caddy works fine but nginx gives 421's. (And it's just for this one upstream, not all.) I tried making a fake upstream that just logs all headers so I could twiddle the headers until they were exactly the same – still nginx fails for that one upstream, while Caddy works.

Answer (score 0):

Add proxy_ssl_name $yourbackendhostname;